# BERT pre-training loss not decreasing

Tags: nlp, loss, bert-language-model

I'm pre-training BERT with Bulgarian dataset on a single Cloud TPU v2 8 using the original parameters (learning rate = 5e-5, training batch size = 32, number of training steps = 100000).
The problem is that it finishes training very fast (3 hours) and the loss doesn't go below 3. My training data is 40 GB and I'm using tensorflow 1.15 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klA2W.jpg)

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?